# Why is this procedure not resizing the heights properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, responsive-design, jquery-events

I have a procedure:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    function rescaleStuff ( )
    {
        jQuery('.children-have-equal-height').each(function(){
            var children = jQuery(this).children();
            var numChildren = children.length;
            if (numChildren > 1) 
            {
                var firstChild = children.first();
                var maxHeight = firstChild.height();
                firstChild.siblings().each(function()
                { 
                    var thisHeight = jQuery(this).height(); 
                    if (thisHeight > maxHeight) 
                        maxHeight = thisHeight;
                });
                children.height(maxHeight);
            }
        });
    }

    rescaleStuff();

    jQuery(window).resize(function()
    { 
         rescaleStuff();
    });
});
```

which is supposed to make all the children of elements with class `children-have-equal-height` be the same height, the height of the tallest child. This works on page load, but after subsequently resizing the window the elements stay the same height as they were when the page loaded. Why is this?

Comment: Use `display: flex` instead of JS.

Comment: @SLaks Won't that only work on new browsers?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 0):

It is because of this function `jQuery(window).load(function() {}`

It only fires on page load.

Put the `jQuery(window).resize(function(){}` and   `function rescaleStuff ( ){}`

outside of the `jQuery(window).load(function() {}`

Comment: No; his code should also work.  (adding the event on load is fine too)

Comment: If he has it outside, he can then call them inside. Right?